# Any way to make a retries for flaky tests using jest-puppeteer?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, jestjs, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I faced with a problem, that there are no built-in way to retry flaky tests in Jest. I'm using Jest + TS + Puppeteer.  Anyone have the same problem or possible solutions\suggestions? 
I tried to implement this one :[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-retries)  , but unsuccessfully.

jest-retries aren't working for me, because I created user and did a lot manipulations, if test failed - retries restarted test in the same chromium tab with same cookies and etc. Thanks in advance !

Code example :

```
const it = require('jest-retries');

describe('any tests', () => {

beforeEach(async () => {
    await page.emulate(devices['Galaxy S5']);
    await page.goto(newSearchUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

});

it('dummy test', 2, async () => {
    await userSignup(); // custom wrapper for signup
    await checkGraphqlSuccess('success dumb event');
    const iconHeader = await waitForElementVisible(favoriteBtnHeader);
    await iconHeader.click();
    const number = await waitForElementVisible(number1);
    const getNumber1 = await page.evaluate(obj => {
        return obj.getAttribute('data-id');
    }, number);
    expect(azaza1).toEqual(getNumber1);
});

afterAll(async () => {
    dumpEvents(fileName);
});
});
```

Comment: you should never get flaky tests. what is TS ? can you share your code? why jest-retries will not work for you?

Comment: @AndreaBisello TS - is typescript , I added answers at your questions in problem description .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried installing jest-circus?

With this test runner you could do next:

```js
//my_perfect_test.js
jest.retryTimes(3) //set maximum retries number

describe('Test', () => {
    test('Test_Test', async () => {
        //test code
        ...
        })
})
```

to minimize flakiness of your tests.

Comment: yes, but it restarts test in same browser window with the same logged user data and etc., maybe there is any way to reset browser data between each retry?

Comment: There is a way, just add:

`const client = await page.target().createCDPSession()`  
`await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCookies')`  
`await client.send('Network.clearBrowserCache')`

Comment: @Nikolai add mentioned code to beforeEach() block and it will cleanup state before each test retry

Answer (score 10):

As of [Jest v27](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestretrytimes), jest-circus is now the default test runner. So the [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60129634/7288576) will work with no extra config.